# Isolating a new user to a specified directory (CentOS 5.3)

Tags: linux, centos, user-management, git, repository

Basically, I'm running this command: useradd -d /var/www/website.com/Pirate -ou 10003 -g psacln -s /bin/bash Pirate

I want the user, Pirate, to only have access to /var/www/website.com/* in order to push and pull to our Git repository, /var/www/website.com/production.git—What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only give access to /var/www/website.com/ to the user, then any tools they need in order to manipulate the git repository must also be somewhere in that directory... this user would not have access to `/usr/bin/git`.

A better way of solving your problem might be to install something like [gitolite](http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/wiki).  gitolite's a bit of work to install (especially for just one user) but rather than giving each person a complete system account, everyone logs in as one specific user via the magic of ssh keys, and those git user keys are [restricted to only run the gitolite server](http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/gitolite-and-ssh.mkd#_restricting_shell_access_distinguishing_one_user_from_another), so they cannot log in with a general shell or SFTP access.